# Android Paypal 2.8.8 Mono wrapper

Tags: android, paypal, mono, xamarin, xamarin.android

I started working on bindings for the latest version of the Paypal SDK, the bindings for an older (also 2.x) version worked, however when I updated the jars and the .so libs it did not compile anymore. The error is that a generated class cannot find the interface it is supposed to have (all obfuscated classes). The interface/type is not in the namespace. I'm not sure how to start tackling this problem.

I uploaded the binding project here: 
https://github.com/tom-mayer/Mono.Droid.Paypal

**Edit:**

I worked the jar with a decompiler and found the following:
The concrete error was that in a generated class "O", the interface "IAF" could not be found in the given namespace. In the jar file the "O" class implements the interface "aF". It seems the code generator does not recognize "aF" as an interface and thus does not name it "IaF" when generating the code. Is that assumption correct?

It was indeed the case and it can be fixed by adding

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.paypal.android.sdk.payments']/interface[@name='aF']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

to the Metadata.xml.

**Edit**

The next error is that all classes implementing two other interfaces are missing a method in the generated code. The interface (in the decompiled jar) expects

```
public abstract String a();
public abstract String a(String paramString);
public abstract String a(Enum paramEnum, String paramString);
```

to be implemented. The first two overloads are present in the generated C# class, but the one with the Enum parameter is missing.

I had a look at the generated api.xml and the interface methods seem to be generated

```
<interface abstract="true" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="aB" static="false" visibility="public">
    <method abstract="true" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="a" native="false" return="java.lang.String" static="false" synchronized="false" visibility="public">
    </method>
    <method abstract="true" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="a"     native="false" return="java.lang.String" static="false" synchronized="false"   visibility="public">
        <parameter name="p0" type="java.lang.Enum">
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="p1" type="java.lang.String">
        </parameter>
    </method>
    <method abstract="true" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="a" native="false" return="java.lang.String" static="false" synchronized="false" visibility="public">
        <parameter name="p0" type="java.lang.String">
        </parameter>
    </method>
</interface>
```

Interesting thing is the class "aZ" (which implements aB) wich should implement these three methods doesn't implement the enum/string overload either in the decompiled jar. How could that even compile in java, since it also doesn't extend from a base class that could implement the missing method?

Any idea?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply removing the methods from the interfaces since they didn't seem to be implemented or used in the java source.

```
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.paypal.android.sdk']/interface[@name='aB']/method[@name='a' and count(parameter)=2]" />
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.paypal.android.sdk']/interface[@name='cC']/method[@name='a' and count(parameter)=2]" />
```

project compiles and runs. I also removed the card.io part since I don't need it. The final wrapper is on github.